# what's the difference between current type and true type?

Tags: java

I am confused what's the difference between current type and true type in java? Are there any examples that can help me to understand?

The typecast is used by the compiler to verify that we are using the types properly.  (This is called the "current type".)
       The true type is used when the code is run.

I am kind of confused what does it mean.

Comment: Please add some context. Where have you read about the terms "true" and "current" types? I don't think those are official terms in java, it' hard to tell what is meant without any source.

Comment: Is it about Generics?

Comment: @PM77-1 Let's not all start guessing what he means. It's up to him to explain.

Comment: I'm guessing he's confused about polymorphism, the type of variable an object is in versus the type of object it really is.

Comment: sorry guys I have edited it.

Comment: Voted to reopen. It is perfectly clear what the OP is asking about. Even though the terminology is "non-standard".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(The following is deliberately non-rigorous.  And it should be noted that your "current type" / "true type" terminology is NOT used in the JLS or the Java Tutorials.)

Here's an example:

```
  Integer i = new Integer(12345);
  Object o = i;
  Integer i1 = o;              // HERE #1
  Integer i2 = (Integer) o;    // HERE #2
```

In this code, there is one object created, and its true type is `Integer`.  This never changes.  Its true type will *always* be `Integer` ... for as long as it exists.

The notion of a current type is actually about what the compiler and runtime system "knowns" about the type of a value.  For example.

- They know that `i` will contain a reference to an instance of `Integer` or some subtype of `Integer`.
- They know that `o` will contain a reference to an instance of `Object` or some subtype of `Object`.

Even though >>we<< know that the reference in `o` is actually a reference to an `Integer`, the compiler is not allowed to known this.  JLS says so!

At the statement  labelled `HERE #1`, the compiler knows that `o` has a current type of `Object` and that has to be assigned to `i1` which has a current type of `Integer`.  That won't work because not every instance of "`Object` or a subtype" is an `Integer`.  (For example a `String` instance isn't.)  Hence the compiler gives you a compilation error.

At `HERE #2`, we added a type cast.  This type cast is telling the runtime system to test that the true type of the object referred to by `o` is `Integer` or a subtype.  If it is, the the compiler and runtime know that it is safe to assign the reference to `i2`.  If not, an exception will be thrown.

---

Q: So why is there this distinction between true types and current types?

A: It is to make polymorphism type-safe.  To allow you to write code that treats an `Integer` as an `Object` ... but not as a `String`.

Q: But I know that `o` actually contains an `Integer`.  So why can't the compiler?

A: It is a simple example:

- Compilers don't have intelligence.  They are not allowed to be intelligent ... because that would imply that all Java compiler are *required* to be intelligent (for portability), and intelligence would make Java compilation many orders of magnitude slower ...
- For sufficiently complicated examples, *you* won't be able to know.
- Computer science theory says that there are examples where it is impossible to know what the true type of an expression will be ... without testing it.